# Why Does A For Loop Return "attempt to get length of a Vector3 value"

Tags: for-loop, roblox

I have no clue what is wrong with this code, it is literally saying that a for loop that is perfectly fine, is attempting to get a vector3 value.

```
local locations = {}
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function SplitString(String)

    local CurrentString = ""
    local x = 1

    for i = 1, #String do

        local FullString = string.sub(String,1,i)
        local Character = string.sub(String,i,i)
        local CurrentString = string.sub(String, x, i)
        print(locations[1])

        if Character == "," then
            CurrentString = string.sub(String,x,i-1)
            table.insert(locations,CurrentString)
            x = i + 1
            CurrentString = string.sub(String, x , i)
            print(locations)
        end

        --Add the character to the string.
        if Character == " " then
            x = i + 1
            CurrentString = string.sub(String, x, i + 1)
        end
        if #FullString + 1 == #String then
            table.insert(locations, CurrentString)
        end
    end
end



Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        local humanoidrootpart = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        
        wait(5)
        
        while humanoidrootpart do
            local location = humanoidrootpart.position
            print(location)
            
            SplitString(location)
            print(locations[1])
            
            local RoundLocatX = math.floor(locations[1]*50)/50
            local RoundLocatZ = math.floor(locations[3]*50)/50
            local RoundLocatXLength = RoundLocatX.length
            local RoundLocatZLength = RoundLocatZ.length
            
            
            if RoundLocatX > 50 then
                print('hi')
            end
            wait(1)
        end
    end)
end)
```

This is the error:

```
ServerScriptService.Terrain Generation:9: attempt to get length of a Vector3 value
```

I would post this on the roblox forum but they are stupid and require some dumb amount of reading time to be able to post on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is pointing at this line :

```
for i = 1, #String do
```

and saying that you are trying to get the length of a Vector3 object. That means that `#String` is not working as expected. So looking at the object you passed into the `SplitString` function...

```
        local location = humanoidrootpart.position
        print(location)
        SplitString(location)
```

Your `location` variable is a Vector3, not a string, and it doesn't support the length operator, `#`.

But you don't have to parse it as a string to get the values out of it. Since it is a [Vector3](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Vector3), you can simply index the different values in it.

```
        local location = humanoidrootpart.Position
        
        local RoundLocatX = math.floor(location.X * 50) / 50
        local RoundLocatZ = math.floor(location.Z * 50) / 50
```

Comment: how would I index the values in it?

Comment: Compare my last code block to your original code. Instead of indexing the values out of the array, `location` is an object with values stored at the indexes `X`, `Y`, and `Z`